# STM32 Ble HID keyboard using HID over GATT profile and UART

Tags: stm32

I am currently working on a project to develop firmware for
X-CUBE-BLE1 for the hardware
STM32L053R8 + STM32 X-NUCLEO-IDB05A1 extension board

with the following requirements.

```
Read ASCII chars from a third party hardware over UART
Send these chars using HID over GATT from
STM32 X-NUCLEO-IDB05A1 extension board to IPAD or other Bluetooth devices.
```

I am new to STM32 and I am struggling with following questions.

> 1) how do I receive chars from UART
>
> 2) how do I sent these chars from UART to HID over GATT using X-CUBE-BLE1.
>
> 3) How do I sent UART data from STM32L053R8 to STM32 X-NUCLEO-IDB05A1 extension board.

I have already looked into `UART` example for `STM32L0`

Please let me know if there are any examples and also documentation for `UART,HID, GATT` .
Kind Regards,
Ven

Comment: There is StdLib for STM32 with API for each of these peripherals. Also you can find STM32 examples (use Google for example).

Comment: Hi Durgpal, Thank you for the answer. I have already searched in google. I could not find the exact lib and examples for HID over GATT

Comment: If you expect to find complete example exactly for your needs, the chance is nearly 0. You have to develop most of it. About library see here: http://www.emcu.it/STM32/STM32Library/TwoWordsConcerningSTM32Library.html

Comment: Thank you Durgpal Singh. I agree.  Now I need to understand how to send UART data from STM32L053R8 to STM32 X-NUCLEO-IDB05A1 extension board using X-CUBE-BLE1. Please let me know if have any idea.

Comment: I hope you have evaluated "Related Tools and Software" at: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF261442  I hope there are examples for UARS communication. (BTW, I am not Durgpal - he edited your question. Author names of comments are after each comment.)